# How to pass multiple checkbox value from one page to other page in joomla?

Tags: joomla

How to pass multiple checkbox value from one page to other page in joomla? I am new to joomla developing and I have required to implement in my site as soon as possible. So please give me ans fastly as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

After the postback of your first page you can collect checkboxes's values in controller function , from there you can start the process to render the next view (page) and assign these checkboxes as view variables to the 2nd page so they will be accesible there.